# module.exports Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to move all react components to separate repo so that they can be shared. I am getting the above error

**ui-react/index.js**

```
'use strict';

import Button from "./components/Button/Button";

module.exports.Button = Button;
```

**FileB**

```
import  {Button} from  'ui-react';
```

When i do this i get an error called.

```
'ui-react' does not contain an export named 'Button'
```

PS: In package.json of ui-react i have set main to index.js and i have also tried import "ui-react/index"

Comment: Why are you using `module.exports` instead of `export { Button };`? Usually mixing module formats is bad idea.

Comment: lack of knowlege

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Comment: can you share more links on this or enlighten me

Comment: You could read through http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html or any number of other posts about ES6 module syntax. `require` and `module.exports` are part of the alternative `CommonJS` module format. The main thing is that you shouldn't really use both together. Some build tooling does allow it, but it usually leads to confusion like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to write module.exports. You can write

```
export { Button };
```

Comment: This answer is underrated and underdocumented! All Node module documentation points to `module.exports`.